# Custom service in feathersjs

Tags: node.js, rest, feathersjs

I try to write a custom service, but it doesn't work at all. I try to post a request and make two update queries in the collections, but i will not work at all

this is my code

```
    // Initializes the `bedrijven` service on path `/bedrijven`
const createService = require('feathers-mongoose');
const createModel = require('../../models/bedrijven.model');
const hooks = require('./bedrijven.hooks');
const filters = require('./bedrijven.filters');
module.exports = function() {
  const app = this;
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');
  const options = {
    name: 'bedrijven',
    Model,
    paginate
  };
  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.post('/bedrijven/setfavo', function(req, res) {
    Promise.all([
      app.service('bedrijven').update({
        owner: req.body.userid
      }, {
        favo: false
      }),
      app.service('bedrijven').update(req.body._id, {
        favo: true
      })
    ]);
  });
  app.use('/bedrijven', createService(options));
  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('bedrijven');
  service.hooks(hooks);
  if (service.filter) {
    service.filter(filters);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this file is included in your main app.js file.

Something like:

```
const bedrijven = require('./bedrijven/bedrijven.service.js');

app.configure(bedrijven);
```

Is there a reason you don't want to use `feathers generate service`? It would take care of these questions for you.

Comment: The code I shared is the file '/bedrijven/bedrijven.service.js. The error I get is thats there must me a validation in other fileds except the 'favo' field. When I update 1 row I can use one item istead update all items of the row.

Comment: Have you checked `req.body.userid` and `req.body._id` and made sure they are matching records in your database for the `owner` and for the `_id` fields?